# using includes in overall php rather then each function

Tags: php

i am very new to php, i am used to writing .net, and i am finding the includes hard to understand and was hoping someone could help me understand how to correctly use an include once in a file, rather than inside each function..

take the following as an example

```
<?php
include 'test.php';

function test($a)
{
 echo $value_from_test_php;
}
?>
```

the above code does not seem to work... however the below does

```
<?php

function test($a)
{
 include 'test.php'

echo $value_from_test_php;
}
?>
```

i am having a hard time figuring out how to make an include work for all functions inside a file, rather then including it inside each function, any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The answer is in the PHP docs: "When a file is included, the code it contains inherits the variable scope of the line on which the include occurs."

Answer (score 1):

It's the scope of variable which is troubling you rather than includes, in PHP generally includes are used where there's a common page/markup to be included on each page, such as footer, header, etc

There are 4 types

- `include`
- `include_once`
- `require`
- `require_once`

The only difference is `include` will throw you an error if something goes wrong and will continue to execute the script where `require` will halt the further execution

You'll get everything here on includes - [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends what is inside the file that you are `include`-ing!  I would never, ever, suggest using `include` inside a function (or loop, or pretty much anything with brackets). Remember, the contents of the file being included are literally just "plopped in" place, right where the `include` statement is. So whatever scope (global, class, function, etc.) you're in when you `include`, is the scope that its contents will be declared in.

Put full class and function definitions in files, and `include` them at the top of the files where they are going to be used.

Comment: May I suggest including some words about Variable scope. That will help remove OP's confusion and build upon this nice piece of advice

Answer (score 0):

First example is not working because you use variable from global scope, if you want to use it then replace `$value_from_test_php` to `$GLOBALS['my_var_name']`

Comment: how do i assign a variable to $globals['my_var_name'] , the php file i'm trying to include is basically made up of about 20 lines if $cfg['ip] = "0.0.0.0" so when i include ( or require ) the file, i can do $cfg['ip'] in the 2nd php file...

Comment: @Brad you dont need to. For example in your test.php file you can have any number of variables in global scope, for instance - $dude = 'dude'; after this line php automatically assign $GLOBALS['dude'] a reference to $dude variable (remember its in global scope!).
And you can use $GLOBALS['dude'] anywere in method, in function, in other files, that is why $GLOBALS array belongs to superglobal arrays

Comment: A few words about `include` - look at it as glue between files, its not like module in python (or package in java) with special scope, if you replace include statement in your first example with code that exists inside test.php you will get the same result. You get error, caused by scope problems, as i said in my post

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not related to includes, but rather [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). By default a variable defined outside a function is not available within the function.

It's difficult to suggest the best solution without knowing exactly what it is you're trying to do, but the documentation (linked above) should get you started.